# Best practices for archiving large build tools in SVN

Tags: svn

We've recently moved to SVN for our code versioning system, and it's been serving us well.  We have an uncommon requirement that we must be able to run our code (and testing) tool-chain 30 years from the time our product becomes available.  This means we need to archive our entire tool-chain, including IDEs, compilers, license servers, the works.  Our naive approach was to create a folder in SVN with our tools, with subfolders for the versions (since different projects may have their production builds created with different versions of the same tool).

However, it seems to me that we will end up storing tens of gigabytes or more worth of these tools alongside our code.  I found some references that older versions of SVN had difficulty in repositories with large binary files, but that seems to have been fixed.  I haven't been able to find any recent metrics on SVN performance with this kind of structure.

Are there any downsides to the naive approach, other than the difficulty in backing up the repository as it gets larger?

The alternatives I see so far are:
1. Create a seperate SVN repository for the build tools
2. Create a network drive for the build tools and keep an index of their checksums to they can be identified down the road.

I realize this may be somewhat subjective, so I'm most interested in any kinds of objective metrics that might be available.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is - don't. SVN (as other similarly) is a source code versioning system and it was never designed to work with large binaries like you mention. You would be much better off establishing a virtual environment and having your toolchain and the rest in VM files instead and stash these some place safe as well as the VM host programs.

Answer (score 0):

I would clearly not store an IDE in an SVN repository, just because you cannot just copy for instance the visual studio folder to some directory and get it running again. You have to archive the installation DVD somewhere. But since that doesn't change, you can use an ordinary backup location (tape, disk, whatever) for this. But the problem goes on: What if the next operating system doesn't support this IDE any more?

Therefore, my idea would be to create a virtual machine with everything installed and running in the state of the released software and then save this image somewhere. Because if you need to run this 30 years from now, it will start by the fact that you will probably not be able to run todays installers on tomorrow's operating system. Better yet, take the whole computer and keep it somewhere safe. And hope that it still works in 30 years. As you (what I guess) don't need to be able to restore *every* version, but only the released ones, the entire thing doesn't look like a problem for SVN to me.

Answer (score 0):

SVN does have the advantage of giving you real version management and an audit trail, if that's important.  I'd create a separate repo for these objects and just use `svn import` to get things in.  You can create working copies (if you need to extract something) with very restricted subsets of the data.  Otherwise you can use a web browser to browse the repo.  Under those restrictions you shouldn't hit any problems - SVN is basically serving as an archive system with version management on top.